# I want to remove the association between two objects via @DeleteMapping. Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Unfortunately, I am unable to deal with the error. I have 2 id's of which the "mieszkanie" is owned by the "deweloper". Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: Please provide an error message and your MieszkanieRepository.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? If you have a field "DeweloperId" in Mieszkanie entity you only need delete Deweloper entity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

two questions:

1. provide an error message and/or stacktrace
2. provide entities between which you have an association.